# How to access a global datacontext from within a component down the components tree

Tags: reactjs

I need to access the global context from within a component that's several levels down the components three, and when I declare the useContext in it, my app ceases to work

This is how my components tree is built

My app defines a global data context, which I access from within the components:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
========>   <GlobalContextProvider>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path={globalConstants.threeDModelPath}>
                            <Route index element={<MainWrapper render={() => <ThreeDModel />} />} />
                            ... /// Other routes...
                        </Route>
                    </Routes>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </GlobalContextProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

This ThreeDModel in turn mounts another component named Model:

```
<Box className={classes.pageContainer}>
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <Canvas>
            <ambientLight intensity={0.4} />
            <directionalLight intensity={2} color={'white'} position={[ 0, 2, 4 ]} />
======>     <Suspense fallback={null}>{texture !== null ? <Model texture={texture} /> : null}</Suspense> 
            {performRig ? <Rig /> : null}
        </Canvas>
    </Box>

</Box>
```

And it's in this Model component where I need to access the GlobalDataContext using the useContext

I just type the useContext sentence

```
const { globalData, setGlobalData } = useContext(GlobalDataContext);
```

And the whole App becomes white, ceases to work

It works fine in other components that aren't this deep

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: any error/warnings displayed?

Comment: Hi Hen, thank you for answering, the whole App becomes white when I try to use useContext, so I drilled down (passed as props) the global state from the upper component that does have access to the globalDataContext